# How to trigger error on fs.rename command if file already exists?

Tags: node.js, file-rename, fs

I have the following code that moves files from one directory to another:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    oldPath = 'firstfile.txt',
    newPath = 'temp/firstfile.txt';

fs.rename(oldPath, newPath, function (err) {
    console.log('rename callback ', err); 
});
```

Is it possible to trigger error if `newPath` file already exists?

Comment: Why not just check first if it exists?

Comment: I want to make it wih single operation

Comment: @TristanFoureur because that would introduce a race condition - the file can be created (or renamed from another process) between the time OP calls `.stat` to check for existence and the time they call `.rename`. This is part of why `.exists` is discouraged in the docs and is deprecated in new versions.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Yes, that's true, but then what solution do you suggest? Except using a mandatory-locking file mount and locking the target path before checking, I see no issue that is 100% race condition proof.

Comment: @Erik can we assume that both the old path and the new path are on the same mounted filesystem?

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum yes

Comment: @TristanFoureur I don't see a 100% race condition proof solution either, but I've only been thinking about it for half a minute and the use case of renaming something only if it doesn't exist sounds common enough to have a solution for.

Comment: Perhaps it's useful to first determine how much of an issue this race condition actually is? If there's only one process performing these actions, the file doesn't contain anything security related _and_ the process isn't running as root, one could argue for some pragmatism...

Answer (score 1):

Try this peice of Code below:

It called the `.exists` method which check if a path exists or not

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    oldPath = 'firstfile.txt',
    newPath = 'temp/firstfile.txt';

fs.exists(newPath, function(exists){
 if (!exists) {
   fs.rename(oldPath, newPath, function (err) {
     console.log('rename callback ', err); 
   });
 } else {
   console.log('The File Already exists');
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you need to do it in one instruction to avoid the race condition (as explained in the comments).

There is at my knowledge no way to do it with the core fs library, but there is a function for doing it in [the extended version](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra).

See the move function, whose default behavior doesen't allow to overwride files:

https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra/blob/master/docs/move.md

```
const fs = require('fs-extra')

fs.move('/tmp/somefile', '/tmp/does/not/exist/yet/somefile', err => {
  if (err) return console.error(err)

  console.log('success!')
})
```